# SQLDataSource inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, controlparameter

for the past days i've been trying to find a solution for my problem but so far i couldn't.
I Have a Gridview that in edit mode, one of the fields have a DropDownList of people that is populated by a Select that uses two other fields of that row (State and City). I tried everything i found on the web about it and i couldn't make it work. Can you help me please?
Code below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"  
        DataKeyNames="id,Municipio,UF" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            ...stuff...
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UF" SortExpression="UF">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UF") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UF") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Municipio" SortExpression="Municipio">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Municipio") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Municipio") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="People" SortExpression="People">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LbPeople" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cultura") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlPeople" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePeopleEdit" DataTextField="People" 
                        DataValueField="People">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" Value='<%# Bind("Municipio") %>' runat="server"/>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden2" Value='<%# Bind("UF") %>' runat="server"/>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePeopleEdit" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbdb %>" 
                        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:somar.ProviderName %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT People FROM Table_People WHERE (Cidade = @Municipio) AND (UF = @UF)"
                        CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Hidden1" Name="Municipio" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Hidden2" Name="UF"        PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
       ...stuff...     
    </asp:GridView>
```

What am i doing wrong?

*UPDATE*
when i click edit, the dropdownlist does not load values.
And if i set the property CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" on SqlDataSource it shows 'Must declare scalar variable @xxx'
I have inspected the hiddenfields and they have values loaded, so the problem is the controlparameter taht does not get the value from it

Comment: You forgot to mention what exactly is not working. Exception? DDL ends up empty? What's the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry for that. The Ddl does not have values, if i set the property CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" on SqlDataSource it shows 'Must declare scalar variable @xxx'

Comment: You're declaring `DataKeyNames` with 3 fields (`DataKeyNames="id,Municipio,UF"`), which `ControlParameter` only supplies 2 fields with parameters (omitting `id` as other required parameter). Try removing unnecessary column field names from `DataKeyNames` property.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have the hidden fields and the sqldatasource before the dropdownlist. The issue you are experiencing is due to when the data is loaded.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"  
    DataKeyNames="id,Municipio,UF" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        ...stuff...
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UF" SortExpression="UF">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UF") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UF") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Municipio" SortExpression="Municipio">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Municipio") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Municipio") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="People" SortExpression="People">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LbPeople" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cultura") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" Value='<%# Bind("Municipio") %>' runat="server"/>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden2" Value='<%# Bind("UF") %>' runat="server"/>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePeopleEdit" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbdb %>" 
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:somar.ProviderName %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT People FROM Table_People WHERE (Cidade = @Municipio) AND (UF = @UF)"
                    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Hidden1" Name="Municipio" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Hidden2" Name="UF"        PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlPeople" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePeopleEdit" DataTextField="People" 
                    DataValueField="People">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   ...stuff...     
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Hello. the time i wrote this question i was in a job of another company and i can't test this solution anymore. Sorry

Comment: OK I see. Hopefully if someone else experience a similar problem they will confirm that this worked for them. I had a similar problem and I found that this resolved the problem for me, which is why I decided to share it here.